# display the linked image on mouse over thumbnails

Tags: jquery, html, css, zooming

Here is my HTML code for thumbnails and the related big image. When i click on thumbnail it will display big image, but i want this to happen with onmouseover. I mean when i place my cursor on thumbnail, it should display big image. How can i convert this.

My html code:

```
<ul class="thumbnails mainimage">
            <li>
              <a  rel="position: 'outside' , showTitle: false, adjustX:-14, adjustY:-560" class="thumbnail cloud-zoom" href="img/category1/sub1/1_big.jpg">
                <img src="img/category1/sub1/1.jpg" alt="" title="">
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a  rel="position: 'outside' , showTitle: false, adjustX:-14, adjustY:-560" class="thumbnail cloud-zoom" href="img/category1/sub1/2_big.jpg">
                <img  src="img/category1/sub1/2.jpg" alt="" title="">
              </a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS psuedo-class `:hover`.

```
.thumbnail:hover {
   background: url('/path/to/myImage.png')
}
```

Comment: if i use like this, i should define class for each image , as every image name different right?

Comment: I'd use an `id`, but yeah

Comment: I did not get you, please can you explain a bit.

Comment: CSS selectors are the fastest with element IDs, not a classname. You can use class names, but an id for each image element would be faster.

Comment: How to use it? i am not getting.. Can you please share if you have any examples

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have time to teach you basic CSS or JavaScript. Please google css hover example and read from there